# Add value to DataGridviewComboBoxColumn without losing focus

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I have a DataGridView in my form that has a ComboBoxColumn that holds a hard-coded list of plants. I also give the user the option to add other plants if "Other" is selected.

[image: Initial datagridview]

When the user selects "Other", he puts the new grass name in the message box.

[image: Adding new name]

However, after OK is clicked, the new name isn't added to the combobox. (The value for Plant Spacing is added programmatically)

[image: After clicking OK]

Only by clicking on another cell in the table is the new name added.

[image]

How can I get the combobox to update without needing to losing focus?

Here is the code I'm using when the Combobox is clicked

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing

    CB = TryCast(e.Control, System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox)
    If CB IsNot Nothing Then
        RemoveHandler CB.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf DGVComboIndexChanged
        AddHandler CB.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf DGVComboIndexChanged
    End If

    ' Other event handlers removed and added here

End Sub

Private Sub DGVComboIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Do what you like with the current ComboBoxCell.
    'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(String.Format( _
    '"The SelectedIndex was changed in ComboBoxCell: {0}" & _
    'Environment.NewLine & _
    '"The current item is: {1}", _
    'Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress.ToString(), _
    'CB.SelectedItem.ToString()))

    Dim TryAgain As Boolean = True
    Dim Letters As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"
    Dim ComboColumn As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

    ComboColumn = DataGridView1.Columns(0)
    Try
        If CB.SelectedItem.ToString = "Other" Then
            While TryAgain
                OtherGrass = Microsoft.VisualBasic.InputBox("Enter the alternate plant name", "Other plant", "")
                If OtherGrass = "" Then
                    'return the cell to ""
                    DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value = ""
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                For i As Integer = 1 To Len(Letters)
                    If InStr(LCase(OtherGrass), Mid(Letters, i, 1)) > 0 Then
                        TryAgain = False
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
                For i As Integer = 0 To ComboColumn.Items.Count - 1
                    If LCase(OtherGrass) = LCase(ComboColumn.Items.Item(i).ToString) Then
                        TryAgain = True
                        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("This plant has already been added.")
                    End If
                Next
            End While
            'ReDim Preserve Grasses(Grasses.GetUpperBound(0) + 1)
            'Grasses(Grasses.GetUpperBound(0)) = OtherGrass
            ComboColumn.Items.Add(OtherGrass)
        End If

        If DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value Is Nothing Then
            DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value = txtSpacMult.Text
        End If
        'If CB.SelectedItem.ToString <> "" Then
        '  For i As Integer = 1 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 2
        '    Dim temp As Boolean = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(i).ReadOnly
        '    Me.DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(i).ReadOnly = False
        '    temp = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(i).ReadOnly
        '  Next
        'End If

        EnableRun()

    Catch ex As Exception
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: try this: after you add the new text to the ComboColumn, set the selectedindex/sletedItem to the one just added.

Comment: I tried that by adding `CB.SelectedIndex = ComboColumn.Items.Count - 1`, but at this point, the combobox CB, which has the SelectedIndex method, does not have the new item, so I'll get an Out of Range exception

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
            ComboColumn.Items.Add(OtherGrass)
```

Put:

```
            CB.Items.RemoveAt(CB.Items.Count - 1)
            CB.Items.Add(OtherGrass)
            CB.Items.Add("Other")
            CB.SelectedItem = OtherGrass
```

You should have the new plant added and selected, and the "Other" entry moved to the end.

Comment: It worked initially, but then I would get a [Datagridview.DataError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.dataerror%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) exceptions (Display and PreferredSize) every time I passed the cursor over the combobox. And when I opened up the combobox again, it didn't contain the newly added plant.